# My game looks fine in the unity editor but when in Android it doesnt work

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

created a simple game for android and everything looks fine in the pc, I have some pictures how it should look in the phone (and how it looks in the unity editor) and the last one is how it looks on the phone, the player doesnt even appear and it looks like its going down for ever (also added my project Hierarchy).
If you guys need some code from the project I will add it.

[image: This is how it looks on the editor]

[image: My project Hierarchy]

[image: How the game looks on the phone]

Comment: Looks like your character has a rigidbody / collider on it, and it is passing through the ground. 

At the start of the scene, place your character at a height from the ground so the physics kicks in before the character passes through the ground collider.

Comment: Does your Editor window use the same resolution as your smartphone? (because aspect ratios seem a little bit off)

Comment: @Farhan you are right, I did that and figured out the problem is that my camera is actually not following the player, so I need to fix my smooth camera follow script, if you have any good smooth camera follow script for Android that I could look into that would be awesome :D

Comment: @Senbazuru yeah its the same resolution its just the way I took the screen-shots haha